# Is there a way to run a perl script on a windows system without having to install anything?

Tags: windows, mysql, perl

I have a handy perl script that I use on my linux systems to check some database information in mysql.  I'd like to have a portable version of this available for Windows (specifically Windows 2008 and 2012) so I can perform the same database checks.

Is there a way I can bundle a runtime (non-install) implementation of perl?  Or do I need to fully install perl?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PortableZIP edition of Strawberry Perl, available [here](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html).

There's also a ZIP edition that doesn't require admin privileges, but you need to run some post-install scripts manually after unzipping.

Depending on your script something like [Perl2Exe](http://www.indigostar.com/perl2exe.php) might also help:

> Perl2Exe is a command line program for converting Perl scripts to
>   executable files.
>
> This allows you to create stand alone programs in Perl that do not
>   require the Perl interpreter. You can ship the executable files
>   without having to ship your Perl source code.
>
> Perl2Exe can generate executables for Windows and Unix target hosts.
>
> Perl2Exe can generate cross-platform code.  For example you can
>   generate code for Solaris from a Linux machine.
>
> Perl2Exe also allows you to create no-console programs using Tk.